# Can a knight move through all squares from its original position?

Tags: analysis, knights

I'm so confused about this. I googled it and read about knight's tours, however they all start from illegitimate positions. I want to know if a knight can move through all squares from its original position (e.g. b8, g8, b1, and g1).

Comment: If the knight lands on all squares in its tour, at some point it is going to hit each  "original square". So take one of the tours you've seen, and use one of those original squares as the starting point and follow the tour from there. When you get to the "end", go back to the beginning until you get back to that original square you used as your starting point.

Comment: @GreenMatt you can't go back to the beginning unless the tour is a circle like in the answer.

Comment: @DonQuiKong: Yes, I should have specified a "closed tour" when I typed that. The point still holds for such tours. Now, can you show me a knight's tour that actually moves in a circle? :-p

Comment: @GreenMatt sure, just take the one in the answer and zoom out ;). But there are open tours so you would have had to prove there is a closed one too

Comment: @GreenMatt Why did you agree with DonQuiKong? Why would it matter if it's not a closed one? Couldn't it backtrack and get everywhere? (Not saying you're wrong. I just don't understand.)

Comment: @ispiro: If it is an open tour, then the tour does NOT cycle back to (one move away from) its beginning. Thus, unless the open tour starts on one of the "beginning squares" you will reach a point where there are no moves available, but there are still squares on the board the knight has not visited.

Comment: @GreenMatt You're assuming `move through all squares from its original position` also means `without visiting the same square twice` (which I don't). So it's just two interpretations of the requirements. That's fine.

Comment: @ispiro: The generally accepted definition of a knight's tour is that the knight visits each square on the board exactly once: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour

Comment: A knight can reach any square from starting on any square.

Answer (score 58):

**Yes, it can**

[image]

This particular [knight's tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#History) is closed, meaning that it starts and finishes in the same square. Therefore, the knight can start at any square on the board and finish on the same square, since it just starts at a different point along the cycle.

Comment: ([image taken from Wikipedia?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#History))

Comment: Except, what kind of sorcery is used from f3 to h7... a double-jump?! EDIT: Ah, it is actually a double jump.

Comment: I suppose you can also make an _open_ knight's tour (i.e. not a cycle) that starts from b1 and terminates at g1?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes, you can!